# Play MP4 videos in Node WebKit

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, nw.js, nwjs

I'm using nodebob for making a nodewebkit (nw.js) desktop app, but the MP4 videos wouldn't play in it ... what should I do?

I tried putting ffmpegso.dll in the same folder where my release exe is but no use

If i use webm video the following code works but for mp4 it says file not found

Here's the code I'm using

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Secure Video Browsing</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="hammer.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/floplayer/skin/skin.css">
    <!-- 3. flowplayer -->
    <script src="js/floplayer/flowplayer.min.js"></script>
    <script>



        var encryptor = require('file-encryptor');
        var $ = require('jquery');
        var path = require('path');
        var gui = require('nw.gui');


        var win = gui.Window.get();






        var key = 'My Super Secret Key';
        var options = {algorithm: 'aes256'};

        window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        var execPath = path.dirname(process.execPath);

        $(document).ready(function () {


            $(".close").click(function () {
                win.close();
            });

            encryptor.decryptFile(execPath + '/wild.eng', execPath + '/wild.mp4', key, options, function (err) {


                var container = document.getElementById("player");
                flowplayer(container, {
                    clip: {
                        sources: [
                            {type: "video/mp4",
                                src: execPath + '/wild.mp4'}
                        ]
                    }
                });

            });
        });



    </script>



</head>
<body>
    <button class="close">Close</button>
    <div id="player">

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you need to post some code. otherwise we can't help you

Comment: @Silve2611 I've updated the code

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to enable proprietary codecs is to download community binaries for the matching NW.js version number you are using:

- https://github.com/iteufel/nwjs-ffmpeg-prebuilt/releases

More information is here:

- https://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/For%20Developers/Enable%20Proprietary%20Codecs/